# AOSP app remove before Build

Tags: build, android-source

How to remove the inbuilt apps such as Camera, calculator from AOSP ? I tried with changes in /target/product/generic_no_telephony.mk, but i didn't get successful result. Help me out

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what version and what target you try to build. As a rule of thumb, you need to remove the corresponding packages from the `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` build variable.

For instance, for Android 5.1 in `core.mk` file you can find the following lines:

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    BasicDreams \
    Browser \
    Calculator \
    Calendar \
    CalendarProvider \
    CaptivePortalLogin \
    CertInstaller \
    Contacts \
    DeskClock \
    DocumentsUI \
    DownloadProviderUi \
    Email \
    Exchange2 \
    ExternalStorageProvider \
    FusedLocation \
    InputDevices \
    KeyChain \
    Keyguard \
    LatinIME \
    Launcher2 \
    ManagedProvisioning \
    PicoTts \
    PacProcessor \
    libpac \
    PrintSpooler \
    ProxyHandler \
    QuickSearchBox \
    Settings \
    SharedStorageBackup \
    Telecom \
    TeleService \
    VpnDialogs \
    MmsService
```

Delete the line `Calculator \` and in the final build you will not find this package.